# How does the Architect think Neo will be swayed by his revelation?

Tags: the-matrix

The Architect reveals to Neo that Trinity is about to die. How does he think Neo will be swayed by his revelation?

Comment: As written, this feels awfully speculation/opinion based and may be closed.

Comment: This might be better as something like "Was saving Trinity the **only** reason why Neo chose that door?", as there may be something in canon which confirms an additional motivation. Whether or not those other motivations would be enough to make him choose the door is something we probably can't find out for sure.

Comment: I disagree. As Merovingian said, 'some might think this is a strange coincidence, but I do not.' and 'where some see coincidence, I see consequence.". @phantom42

Comment: I think the first part of the question -- about Neo choosing the left door if Trinity hadn't been threatened -- requires speculation. However, the rest of the question -- about why the Architect didn't order the Agents to stand down and whether it was part of the Oracle's game -- is good.

Comment: This seems extremely speculative. There were multiple reasons why Neo didn't develop the "profound detachment" from the Human race that would have been required in order to choose the other door. This included (but wasn't limited to) his love for Trinity.

Comment: Escoce's answer is first-rate. I edited my question so as to keep his answer open. @Null

Comment: I liked the original: *Is being in love the only thing that separates Neo from his predecessors?*

Comment: ... Which [you asked](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/117741/what-would-be-the-choice-given-to-neos-five-predecessors-when-they-were-in-the) an hour ago.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that Neo represents the accumulation of flaws in the system, that's Neo's compassion for humanity was expressed as love for Trinity, and coupled with the fact that the Architect made a calculation error. The Architect calculated that the chances that Neo would rationally choose the *desired* door would be improved if Trinity was certain to die. However, Neo did not believe that Trinity's death was certain, and felt he could and needed to save her, couldn't live without her, and so made an irrational decision which is so common among humans when faced with a choice between what's right and what's *love*.

Neo chose love over rational behavior. That was the Oracle's gambit.

Comment: Makes perfect sense! A miscalculation on the part of the Architect.

Answer (score 0):

To expand Escoce's first-rate answer, I'd say that the Architect reveals Trinity's pending death to his advantage. He believes that she is the most important reason for Neo to return to the Matrix. By eliminating her it would also mean eliminating the possibility of that choice. Therefore, the only thing Neo needs to consider now is to save billions of life instead of hers.

However, Neo still believes he can save her and makes the choice the machine couldn't understand.